# Converting "-" to a "0" in R

Tags: r

I have a column `Apps` in dataframe `dframe`

that looks like this:

```
    Apps
1    31
2    12
3    10
4    33
5    -
```

I need the column to be type int instead of String so I need to convert the 5th row to a 0.

```
    Apps
1    31
2    12
3    10
4    33
5    0
```

Comment: How did you read this data into R? It probably would have been a good idea to use `read.table(..., na.strings="-")` to read it in as missing from the beginning.

Comment: `dframe$Apps[ dframe$Apps == "-" ] <- "0"`? I agree with MrFlick, though, as a value of "0" is not the same as the hyphen, which many programs (not R) interpret as "not a valid number". I'm guessing that as it is now, it is `character`. Use the `na.strings=` argument, it is very worth it to you to read it in correctly the first time and allow `read.table` to handle the column classes for you. It is not perfect, but anything else suggests something else is wrong with your data. (BTW: `dframe$Apps <- as.numeric(dframe$Apps)` might suffice for you.)

Answer (score 3):

```
dframe$Apps[dframe$Apps == "-"] <- "0"
dframe$Apps <- as.integer(dframe$Apps)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with `ifelse` and the `tidyverse` approach:

```
require(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  mutate(Apps = ifelse(Apps == "-", 0, Apps))

  Apps
1    4
2    3
3    2
4    5
5    0
```

Dataset:

```
df <- read.table(text = "    Apps
1    31
2    12
3    10
4    33
5    -", header = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

```r
dframe$Apps <- as.integer(gsub("-", "0", dframe$Apps, fixed = TRUE))
```

will give you an integer column as I suspect you want.